# Angular ui-bootstrap carousel - image not loading

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
    var app = angular.module('app',['ui.bootstrap'])
app.controller('getResources',['$scope',function($scope){
    $scope.myInterval = 5000;
    $scope.noWrapSlides = false;
    $scope.active = 0;
    var slides = $scope.slides = [];
    var currIndex = 0;

    $scope.addSlide = function() {
      slides.push({
        image: [
            "https://webmppcapstone.blob.core.windows.net/fruitsimages/strawberries.jpg",
            "https://webmppcapstone.blob.core.windows.net/fruitsimages/banana.jpg",
            "https://webmppcapstone.blob.core.windows.net/fruitsimages/avocado.jpg",
            "https://webmppcapstone.blob.core.windows.net/dairy-royaltyfree/wholemilk.png"
        ][slides.length % 4],
        text: ['Nice image','Awesome photograph','That is so cool','I love that'][slides.length % 4],
        id: currIndex++
      });
      for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        $scope.addSlide();
    }
}
}]);
```

The images are not loading. What am i doing wrong?.
I'm trying to push the images into the slides.image object and reference them as a ng-src in my html but it seems not to be loading at all.

Answer (score 0):

You are using adding the slides to the local variable `slides` which is not attached to the scope. Use the `$scope.slides` instead

```
var app = angular.module('app',['ui.bootstrap'])
app.controller('getResources',['$scope',function($scope){
    $scope.myInterval = 5000;
    $scope.noWrapSlides = false;
    $scope.active = 0;
    $scope.slides = [];
    var currIndex = 0;

    $scope.addSlide = function() {
      $scope.slides.push({
        image: [
            "https://webmppcapstone.blob.core.windows.net/fruitsimages/strawberries.jpg",
            "https://webmppcapstone.blob.core.windows.net/fruitsimages/banana.jpg",
            "https://webmppcapstone.blob.core.windows.net/fruitsimages/avocado.jpg",
            "https://webmppcapstone.blob.core.windows.net/dairy-royaltyfree/wholemilk.png"
        ][$scope.slides.length % 4],
        text: ['Nice image','Awesome photograph','That is so cool','I love that'][$scope.slides.length % 4],
        id: currIndex++
      });
      for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        $scope.addSlide();
    }
}
}]);
```